# AngularJS multiple projects with the same base

Tags: javascript, angularjs, git, github, ionic-framework

I'm developing an AngularJS/Ionic.v.1 App and my goal is doing an product. In detail, I want to create an core project and multiple child project that incorporate the core.
Every child project can have different customization (change color, change images and new features).

All this one is necessary because if I have an bug or global new feature I must fix or develop one time and not n.

On this project I'm using GIT so I could create an brach for every child project (clients) and my develop is the core but I'm not convinced that this is the best practice.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you in advance.